# How do you copy more than one csv file to one csv file in command prompt skipping column headers?

Tags: excel, csv, command

I have 20 .csv files and want to copy them all to one .csv file. All 20 has column headers in them and has more lines than the Excel limit of 1,048,576 lines.

I am capable of using **more +1 Book1.csv > test.csv** and it then copies what ever is in Book1 to a new book called test.csv without the column header. I can do this with each file but then i sit with another 20 files. Afterwards i must then copy the extra 20 files to another folder and do **copy *.csv comb.csv** where all the 20 files gets copied into one file named comb.csv.

I am not very experienced in using command prompt, but is there anyway that i can combine the two statements  **more +1 Book1.csv > test.csv** , **copy *.csv comb.csv** so that i don't need to create another 20 files that needs to be copied to another folder?

Comment: Do you want to do this using Excel VBA or another scripting environment??

Comment: I want to import the final csv file into an Access database